# How to create a button on custom page backend

Tags: admin, custom-button, custompage

I'm looking to add a button that executes my own custom code.

I've successfully created the page, along with a button but I can't for the life of me get it todo anything. I've stripped it back down to basics, where I just display the page with the layout form etc.

Please see my code below, I wondered if anyone would be able to help me/point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

My Controller

```
    <?php

namespace Ozark\Maxoptra\Controller\Adminhtml\ExportEmail;


use Laminas\Form\Element\Button;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\ResultPageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    private $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create(); // this crete an empty page
        return $resultPage;// this show page
    }

}
```

Template

```
  <h2 class="export main">Test info@xxxxxxx.co.uk</h2>
<br>
<form class="export button">
    <input type="submit" value="Run Export" name="runExport" />
</form>
```

Comment: try check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/317429/82670

Comment: Great, thank you. But I'm only looking to have a singular button on the screen, when pressed executes code which sends a email containing order data. I've got it working as a console command, just can't figure out how to link a button.

Comment: in this link there are sample module. what you are looking for is in that module.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UFMtTOkwbaPKbIdAZ_DDZKJkZHvpIoPW/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in magento 2.x ui components are used for adding the classic orange buttons at the top (saving, modifying, deleting etc.).
Are you interested in such a thing or a normal button?

Cheers

Comment: Oh okay, a normal button if possible?

Comment: yes but usually, on backend buttons are all created by ui component. Follow this guide for create a page within pthml file. When you got the phtml file you will be able to insert as many buttons as you prefer. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194368/how-to-create-a-new-page-without-using-cms